Commuting measurements performed in the different order?
The question is in the context of stabilizer measurements where we have commuting stabilizers and we can choose to measure them in a different order, as is commonly done in the surface code. I choose a simpler example with just two qubits.
The observable $X_1X_2$ commutes with $Z_1Z_2$. Suppose I wish to record both these observables on some state of two qubits.
Can I can perform $X_1, Z_1, X_2, Z_2$ in that order instead? The logic there being that since $Z_1$ and $X_2$ commute, I can build the outcomes $X_1X_2$ and $Z_1Z_2$ from those four measurements. On the other hand, if I perform these four measurements in the order $X_1, Z_2, X_2, Z_1$, this fails - is this also correct?

There is a more important intermediate question. Can you perform the measurements
$$
X_1,X_2,Z_1,Z_2
$$
and still record the same results?
You cannot divide the two-qubit observables into two one-qubit observables like that. Yes, If you wanted the observable $X_1X_2$, it is technically enough to measure $X_1$ and $X_2$, but you're measuring too much. You're projecting the system onto a one-dimensional subsystem rather than a two-dimensional one.
Imagine, for example, that my state started as $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. This is a $+1$ eigenstate of both $ZZ$ and $XX$, so you know what result you should always get. But, instead, let's perform the proposed measurement. We'll get answers $a$ and $b$ for results of the two $X$ measurements, where $ab=1$, i.e. $a=b$. Let's pretend that $a=b=1$, so the output state must be $|++\rangle$. Now measure the two $Z$s. You can get any of the 4 possible outcomes with equal probability. This includes half the time when you get the wrong answer for the $ZZ$ observable.

You can indeed perform the measurement of a set of commuting observables in any order you like.
The issue with what you suggest is that you will be measuring 4 observables, $X_1, X_2, Z_1$ and $Z_2$, which do not all commute with each other.
If you measure $Z_1$ some time after measuring $X_1$, the measurement will be entirely random (50/50). This is what happen in the Stern-Gerlach experiment. The reconstructed $X_1X_2$ measurement from the successive measurements of $X_1$, $Z_1$, $X_2$, $Z_2$ will not correspond to the actual measure of $X_1X_2$ because the intermediate $Z_1$ measurement will randomize the value of $X_1$ (and also $X_1X_2$).
You have to measure directly the two observables $X_1X_2$ and $Z_1Z_2$ without relying on measurement reconstruction in this case.
